# pyenv cannot switch python version and cannot install 3.6.8

Tags: python, pyenv

I installed pyenv with homebrew and their versions are Homebrew 3.3.11 and pyenv 2.2.3. After I run install pyenv, I've add these code to my ~/.zshrc

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

when I use try to install python 3.6.8 I got these error:

```
$ pyenv install 3.6.8
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.6.8.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/Python-3.6.8.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.8...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.1 using python-build 2.2.3-7-g39f1b141)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/4q/cdx7_wjd44jfq0r6db6f0vrm0000gr/T/python-build.20220122234617.8185
Results logged to /var/folders/4q/cdx7_wjd44jfq0r6db6f0vrm0000gr/T/python-build.20220122234617.8185.log

Last 10 log lines:
        ret = sendfile(in, out, offset, &sbytes, &sf, flags);
              ^
./Modules/posixmodule.c:10432:5: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
    Py_FatalError("abort() called from Python code didn't abort!");
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include   -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include   -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wstrict-prototypes   -I. -I./Include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/Users/h33704/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/include  -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/Users/h33704/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/pwdmodule.c -o Modules/pwdmodule.o
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [Modules/posixmodule.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 warning generated.
```

However, I can successfully install python 3.9.10 and 3.10.0.
but cannot switch version as I expected, just like:

```
$ python versions
* system (set by /Users/xxx/.pyenv/version)
  3.10.0
  3.9.10

$ pyenv global 3.10.0 

$ python versions
  system (set by /Users/xxx/.pyenv/version)
* 3.10.0
  3.9.10

$ python
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 11:48:04) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I added this alias to ~/.zshrc before:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

I think the environment of python on my laptop is a mess...
How can I fix or reset my environment?